# 2 cloumn layout not displaying as it should

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have added a 2 column layout to my contact form.

the only thing is it does not display in 2 columns but single columns.

my html is:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="column1">
        <h1>You can talk to me. I don't bite...</h1></div><br><br>
        <h5>You can contact me by the form opposite or by one of the following:</h5><br><br>
        <img src="/icons/mail.png" name="mail">kevin@kh.co.uk
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
        <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
            <p>Name*</p> <input type="text" name="name">
            <p>Your Company Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
            <p>Email*</p> <input type="text" name="email">
            <p>Telephone*</p> <input type="text" name="email">
            <p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
            <small>Fields marked with a * symbol are required. </small>
            <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css is:

```
#container {
    float: left;
    width: 98%;
    position:relative;
}
#column1, #column2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left; 
    position:relative;
}
```

please can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

thank you.
Kev

Comment: width: 98%; ??? it must be something like 48% to display them near each other

Comment: @Vladimir that's the container...

Comment: It could be the css for the elements inside the columns.

Does anything inside them have extra padding or margin that would cause the stacking?

Comment: It's because you have an extra </div> tag after your </h1>. Remove it

Comment: Oh yes ,you should not use 50% , try something like 49% for each of them , cause there is reserved space for borders and also padding can affect on that, if you want them to display with 50% use display: table-cell to both of them

Comment: DAVID HAS EDITED MY ORIGINAL POST AND REMOVED THE PROBLEM. WHAT IS HE PLAYING AT?

Comment: @KevHopwood I edited it back in

Comment: thank you. please one up me so that it wipes off my uncalled for -1.

Comment: @KevHopwood I wouldn't advise asking for votes.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

my closing div tag for `<div id="column1">` was not at the end of my column 1 content.

thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. You have too many closing  tags. Remove the one after the closing  tag and it will be fine:

See [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aUbVp/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing div tag on the same line as the H1, It shouldnt be there so remove it.

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WT6zC/

```
    <div id="container">
<div id="column1">

<h1>You can talk to me. I don't bite...</h1><br><br>
<h5>You can contact me by the form opposite or by one of the following:</h5><br><br>
<img src="/icons/mail.png" name="mail">kevin@kh.co.uk

</div>
<div id="column2">
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name*</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Your Company Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email*</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Telephone*</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<small>Fields marked with a * symbol are required. </small>
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not written code properly.
extra

```
</div>
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/kDdtc/)